# JSON Single Line Parse to Multi-Line CSV with Python

Tags: python, json, csv, plaid

I am a Python noob, and working with the Plaid API to get bank transactions.  I would like each transaction to be it's own line, and I only want to pull four values per record: date, _account, name & amount, and populate a CSV file with that data.  I have the below code which populates a single line CSV (JSON file also attached).  I can't seem to figure out what I am looking for as far as examples on how to do this after a bit of Googling.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
import csv

#Configuration
from plaid import Client

Client.config({
    'url': 'https://api.plaid.com'
})

#Connect to Plaid
from plaid import Client
from plaid import errors as plaid_errors
from plaid.utils import json

client = Client(client_id='test_id', secret='test_secret')
account_type = 'suntrust'

try:
    response = client.connect(account_type, {
    'username': 'plaid_test',
    'password': 'plaid_good'
    })
except plaid_errors.PlaidError:
     pass
else:
    connect_data = response.json()

#Get transactions from Plaid
response = client.connect_get()
transactions = response.json()

#Save the transactions JSON response to a csv file in the Python Projects directory
with open('transactions.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(transactions, outfile)

csvfile = open('transactions.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('transactions.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("date", "_account","name","amount")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

[JSON FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djfp2iead6x9s6n/transactions.json?dl=0)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Take a look at the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class in the Python documentation. Would make it a lot simpler to convert a JSON into a csv.

Comment: json code is better for solve you problem

Comment: John Zwinck - I should have been more clear in my post, I am trying to populate a multi-line CSV file as opposed to the one line I am getting now, and only populate 4 columns from the JSON file.

Comment: It's a malformed JSON. There are multiple name fields with string and int entries.

Comment: Inspect it here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ or here: http://chris.photobooks.com/json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this over-complicated and confusing JSON with CSV.  Hat tip to @thalesmallo who beat me to the punch on using the `DictWriter` class.  Try this:

```
import csv
from plaid import Client

Client.config({
    'url': 'https://api.plaid.com'
})

#Connect to Plaid
from plaid import Client
from plaid import errors as plaid_errors
from plaid.utils import json

client = Client(client_id='test_id', secret='test_secret')
account_type = 'suntrust'

try:
    response = client.connect(account_type, {
        'username': 'plaid_test',
        'password': 'plaid_good'
    })
except plaid_errors.PlaidError:
     pass
else:
    connect_data = response.json()
response = client.connect_get()
data = response.json()
transactions = data['transactions'] # see https://plaid.com/docs/api/#data-overview

#Save the transactions JSON response to a csv file in the Python Projects directory
header = ("date", "_account", "name", "amount")
with open('transactions.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for x in transactions:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

Comment: Kudos and thanks to both @2ps and thalesmello.  The code worked beautifully with a few minor edits.  I looked at the suggested documentation which I found to be very helpful (although I didn't quite get all the way there).  I'm very appreciative to everybody for the help.